# creating an upload functionality in spring, getting error threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, controller, postman

Relevant files - migrationruleserviceimpl

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import javax.inject.Named;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Named
public class MigrationRuleServiceImpl implements MigrationRuleService {

@Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public String migrationRuleUpload(MultipartFile file){

         if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                    BufferedOutputStream stream =
                            new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("lul")));
                    stream.write(bytes);
                    stream.close();
                    return "You successfully uploaded ";

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return "You failed to upload  => " + e.getMessage();
                }
            } else {
                return "You failed to upload because the file was empty.";
            }
    }
}
```

migrationruleservice

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

public interface MigrationRuleService {


    String migrationRuleUpload(MultipartFile file);

}
```

migrationrulecontroller

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload")
public class MigrationRuleController {



    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String migrationRuleUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        return migrationRuleUpload(file);
    }

}
```

when i am trying this out in postman, im getting internal server error 500 - error message from tomcat logs:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError at MigrationRuleController.migrationRuleUpload(MigrationRuleController.java:17)
<the previous line repeated bazilion of times>
```

What can possibly be wrong with this?

Comment: Forgot to add, the error line java.lang.StackOverflowError at MigrationRuleController.migrationRuleUpload(MigrationRuleController.java:17)  is repeated like 50 times, don't know if its relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is pretty clear - you call some function recursively. Here is the culprit:

```
public String migrationRuleUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    return migrationRuleUpload(file);
}
```

This method simply calls itself. Instead you probably wanted to inject `MigrationRuleService` instance and call the `migrationRuleUpload` on that instance:

```
public class MigrationRuleController {
    @Inject
    private MigrationRuleService migrationRuleService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String migrationRuleUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        return migrationRuleService.migrationRuleUpload(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: such an obvious error- THANK YOU. I even had other, working methods similar to this one, and every single one of them had the call to the service,  just had to look them up LOL. I don't know who and where you are but i will find you... and i will kiss you.